# How do I compare two list of data that contains a certain number in Excell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

How do I compare two lists of columns that contains a certain number? Please look at my example below:

```
Column 1   Column 2
-------------------
300        Room 305
301        Room 306
302        Room 307
303        Room 308
304        Room 309
305        Room 310
306        Room 311
307        Room 312
308        Room 313
309        Room 314
310        Room 315
```

As you can see, is there a formula that shows me that 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, and 310 is in both column? Even though column two have other letter/words infront of it?

Answer (score 2):

Changing "Column 1" to A and "Column 2" to B, and assuming you are starting in row 1, try the following in column C:

```
=vlookup(right(b1,3),a:a,1,false)
```

Fill column C with this function, and you will wind up with a list of room numbers that are in both columns, as well as #N/A next to any number in B that does not appear in A.

EDIT: you may have to use the following if column A is in general/number format:

```
=vlookup(numbervalue(right(b1,3)),a:a,1,false)
```

Or, if you are using a version of Excel older than 2013, you can use the following (sketchy, but works to coerce the string to a number):

```
=vlookup(right(b1,3)+0,a:a,1,false)
```

Comment: you are my hero, and i love you forever.

Comment: Haha no problem, I'm glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

I am using Office 2007 and the formula you show almost works for me.
You need just value instead of number value like so:

```
=VLOOKUP((VALUE(RIGHT(B10,3))),A$3:A$13,1,FALSE)
```

This is assuming that Column 1 is in A1 and Cloumn 2 is in B1 and the room numbers start in A3.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).